# Access in deallocated memory

Tags: c++, memory, delete-operator

I found strange problem which there are no runtime error while accessing in deallocated memory.

```
class Test {
public:
  Test(int idx) : c(idx) {}
  ~Test() {
    std::cout << "destructor\n";
  }
  void Delay() {
    Sleep(500);
    std::cout << "delay " << c << "\n";
  }
protected:
  int c;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  for (int idx = 0; idx < 100; idx++) {
    Test* test = new Test(idx);
    Test*temp = test;
    delete test; test = NULL;
    temp->Delay();
  }

  std::cout << "Exit\n";

  Sleep(1000);
  return 0;
}
```

The variable "test" is deallocated, and temp has previous memory address of "test".
But calling Delay() function with "temp" doesn't a runtime error.
How can I understand it?

In Delay() function, checking IsBadXXXPtr() function found that no memory error.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It happens because of bad luck. You are invoking undefined behavior by using an invalid pointer. You are not guaranteed a runtime error, you're not guaranteed of anything. It's undefined.

The practical reason it doesn't crash for you is because `Delay()` doesn't actually access any member variables. So basically, `Delay()` could also be written as a free-standing function (out of the class).

Regarding `IsBadReadPtr`, show some code to demonstrate what you're talking about. But keep in mind that `IsBadReadPtr` is an OS-level call, while `new` and `delete` are language constructs. Just as you cannot mix `new` and `free`, you can't rely on interoperability between `new`/`delete` and `IsBadReadPtr`.

Edit: I say bad luck because your code has serious problems, but it's invisible because of chance. It's better luck if the app crashes, revealing the bugs.